# How does an update from the child component in React get conveyed to the parent?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a react-express Todo list and cant seem to update the Todo item from the TodoItem component which is in the main App component. when i write the axios function to modify the database from the child component itself the Todo is getting blanked out after a state refresh.

I have tried sending data from the Child component to the parent but with no result.

//App.jsx

```
                {this.state.data.map(data => (
                  <TodoItem
                    data={data}
                    key={data.id}
                    delete={() => this.removeFromDatabase(data)}
                    edit={() => this.setState({ editing: data.id })}
                    update={(data)=>this.updateDatabase(data)}
                  />
                ))}
```

//TodoItem.jsx

```
  handleSubmit = ()=>{
      var data = this.props.data;
      console.log(this.state.editText,data);
    // this.props.update(this.state.editText);
    axios.post('http://localhost:3007/todo/updateTodo',{
        id:data._id,
        update:this.state.editText
    })
    this.setState({isEditing:false})
  }
  //the input where we enter the edited value.
            <input
            type="text"
            style={editStyle}
            value={this.state.editText}
            className="form-control"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onBlur = {this.handleSubmit}
            onKeyDown ={this.handleKeydown}
          />
```

After submitting, the updated value must be shown, instead the todo is blank.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data from child to parent component you need to use `redux`. With redux you can can `dispatch` `actions` from child component which will mutate the `reducer` state. And then you can use this state anywhere in your project. In your case this reducer state can be used to update the parent component.